# How do I make routes case insensitive with Angular

Tags: angularjs

How can I make routing in angular case insensitive? For example if I have a route for www.example.com/home which looks like this:

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/home', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/home/home-page.tmpl.html',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'home'
  });
```

How can I also set it up so that it would work with.

www.example.com/Home | www.example.com/HOME | www.example.com/HoMe etc?

Comment: I think it depends on server...

Comment: Is there a way to do it right in angular? or would it require changing the case with the server?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems you can simply set this property to make all route matching case insensitive

```
$routeProvider.caseInsensitiveMatch = true;
```

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider#caseInsensitiveMatch

Answer (score 5):

There is an option for case insensitivity:

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/home', {
       templateUrl: 'pages/home/home-page.tmpl.html',
       controller: 'HomeCtrl',
       controllerAs: 'home',
       caseInsensitiveMatch: true
});
```